# Manipulate stack trace of exception before throwing (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a lazy evaluation library in Python which allows the user to write normal code, while it is evaluated at a later point in time. A problem is that the exceptions are quite confusing. This is why I would like to throw the exception with a modified stack trace. It should look as if the exception was triggered without lazy evaluation at all (or just with a short hint).

This is what I have already tried. I didn't find a better way to get a traceback, but if possible I would prefer not to throw an Exception in create_tb.

```
import sys

def create_tb():  # Capture the stack trace
  try:
    raise Exception("A")
  except:
    _, _, tb = sys.exc_info()
    return tb


def raise_with_tb(tb):  # It should look like "B" was triggered in create_tb
  raise Exception("B").with_traceback(tb)


tb = create_tb()
raise_with_tb(tb)
```

But the output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../test.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise_with_tb(tb)
  File ".../test.py", line 12, in raise_with_tb
    raise Exception("B").with_traceback(tb)
  File ".../test.py", line 5, in create_tb
    raise Exception("A")
Exception: B
```

Instead of something like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../test.py", line 5, in create_tb
    raise Exception("B")
Exception: B
```

Is this possible?

I am relatively new to Python. If there is more phytonic way to achieve my goal, I am glad for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to suppress context of previous exceptions occured:

```
try:
    raise Exception('original exception message')
except Exception as exc:
    my_custom_exception = Exception('my custom message')
    my_custom_exception.__suppress_context__ = True
    raise my_custom_exception
```

It gives the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex.py", line 6, in <module>
    raise my_custom_exception
Exception: my custom message
```

With line `my_custom_exception.__suppress_context__ = True` commented the traceback also have previous exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex.py", line 2, in <module>
    raise Exception('original exception message')
Exception: original exception message

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex.py", line 6, in <module>
    raise my_custom_exception
Exception: my custom message
```

But I am not sure that it 1) is pythonic way 2) is really what you need.

Comment: Thank you. This is useful to know, but does not solve my problem.